# Pytest : How to update jenkins url in pytest html report instead of local path

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pytest

i am able to see below path created in my html report , i am able to open this path from html when it is a local job , but when i run in jenkins ,this link wont work , i am able to see metadata have url and workspace info , can i use this meta data to generate proper links in html file , so that i will be able to open them from jenkins page .

```
href="file:///space/scratch/jenkins/navarro/workspace/coverage_regression/dut/python/.simtest/NavarroSimTestSystem/default/TestJaxi/test_py_jaxi_read_version_reg_ss/TestJaxi.test_py_jaxi_read_version_reg_ss-2458081572_simulate.log" type="text/plain">TestJaxi.test_py_jaxi_read_version_reg_ss-2458081572_simulate.log
```

Comment: The file has to be hosted somewhere in order for the link to work. You can store the file as Jenkins artifact and replace the link with the link to artifact (you will have to assemble the link yourself though, e.g. extracting job ID etc from Jenkins environment variables).

Comment: thank you @hoefling , i have already implemented in similar way , i am able to get . any idea how to update the summary link ,

------------------------------ generated html file: file:///space/scratch/kkt/trails/soc/python/checking.html ---------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show test results in Jenkins job? I have found it easier to generate junit.xml using --junitxml switch and point Jenkins to the Junit XML path. It shows all test results data. Or have you tried the 'html-publisher-plugin'.

Comment: thank you for the reply , i am generating xml but it when i open it up in jenkins, it shows the std_out but not the link to the simulation .

Answer (score 0):

i have found by doing below way .

```
    def pytest_configure(self, config):
        # below lines has been added to manipulate the log path in html report while running in jenkins 
        if 'BUILD_URL' in config._metadata:
            self.build_url = os.path.join(config._metadata['BUILD_URL'],'artifact')

    @pytest.mark.optionalhook
    def pytest_html_results_table_html(self, report, data):
            if test_artifact_simulate and os.path.isfile(test_artifact_command):
            from py.xml import html
            ul = html.ul()
            if self.build_url != None :
                simulate_log = test_artifact_simulate[test_artifact_simulate.find('dut'):]
                print 'KKT simulate log is %s' %simulate_log
                jenkins_log_path = os.path.join(self.build_url,simulate_log) 
                print 'KKT jenkins_log_path log is %s' %jenkins_log_path
                li = html.li(html.a(os.path.basename(test_artifact_simulate),
                    href= jenkins_log_path, type="text/plain"))
            else :
                li = html.li(html.a(os.path.basename(test_artifact_simulate),
                    href='file://' + test_artifact_simulate, type="text/plain"))
            ul.append(li)
            div = html.div()
            div.append(html.p("Test artifacts:"))
            div.append(ul)
            data.append(div)
```